# Set parameters in action post url and change it asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, http

I have this code in a design asp.net Form. After pressing a SEND button by a form called from that URL: "https://static-content.vnforapps.com/v2/js/checkout.js", it redirects to the action url. I want to send some parameters to that url with post method with asp.net. I tried with some methods but it fails. Is there a way to send it with javascript or c#? Thanks

```
<td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <form id="formBoton" action="https://www.sequence.com/seq/seq_payments_new_answer.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
                            <script type="text/javascript" id="javascriptBoton" src="https://static-content.vnforapps.com/v2/js/checkout.js"
                                data-sessiontoken='<%=sessionToken%>'
                                data-channel='<%=channel%>'
                                data-merchantid='<%=merchantId%>'
                                data-buttonsize='<%=buttonSize%>'
                                data-buttoncolor='<%=buttonColor%>'
                                data-merchantlogo='<%=merchantLogo%>'
                                data-merchantname='<%=merchantName%>'
                                data-formbuttoncolor='<%=formButtonColor%>'
                                data-showamount='<%=showamount%>'
                                data-cardholderemail= '<%=cardholderemail%>'
                                data-purchasenumber='<%=purchasenumber%>'
                                data-amount='<%=amount%>'
                                <%--data-recurrence='<%=recurrence%>'--%>
                                data-expirationminutes='<%=expirationminutes%>'
                                data-timeouturl='<%=timeouturl%>'>
                              </script> 
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden fields to send some parameters :

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" action="https://www.sequence.com/seq/seq_payments_new_answer.aspx" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="input1"></input>

        <input type="hidden" name="txtAmount"  runat="server" id="txtAmount"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
```

and in the page load i have:

```
txtAmount.Value = "10000";
```

Comment: I tried with that way and didn't worked. My summit button comes from a formulary called by a js url